# React/Redux rendering a list that's updating every second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react component that receives props from the redux store every second. The new state has an array that's different than the last array. To be specific, every second an element is added to the array. For example:
in one state the array is:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

the next state

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

My reducer:

```
return {
  ...state,
  myList: [ payload, ...state.myList.filter(item => payload.id !== item.id).slice(0, -1) ]
}
```

Now, in my react component I am subscribing to this state and for every change, the list is re-rendered.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyRow from './MyRow';

class MyList extends Component {

    render() {

        return (

        <div>

            {this.props.myList.map((list, index) => (
                <MyRow key={list.id} data={list}/>
            ))}

        </div>

        );
    }
}

function select({ myList }) {
    return { myList };
}

export default connect(select)(MyList);
```

In MyRow.js

```
import { PureComponent } from 'react';

class MyRow extends PureComponent {

    render() {

    const data = this.props.data;

        return (
            <div>
                {data.id} - {data.name}
            </div>
        );

    }
}
export default MyRow;
```

Now, my problem is: It's costly for me to re-render every element that has been already rendered. The MyRow heavily uses styled components and other expensive operations.
This is causing react to re-render the whole list every second when the state is updated. This gets worst if updates come in less than 1 seconds, like 4 updates per second. The react app simply crashes in this case.

Is there any way to only add the newly added item to the list and not re-render the whole list?

Thanks

Comment: Really good article about performance optimization you can find [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html).

Comment: Looks like your using keys correctly this allows react to understand which elements are new as such the vDOM should not re render all the items rather update as required  https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html.

Comment: @Reza can you please checkout my detailed answer, and if there's something unclear, then please let me know.

Answer (score 14):

You're using [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), that do shallow comparison, then your component `MyRow` should **not** be rerendered on each new item being added (*Please follow my code example below*).

> Is there any way to only add the newly added item to the list and not re-render the whole list?

According to your question - **Yes, using `PureComponent` should render only 1 time the new item**:

Here's what the [React's docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) says:

> If your React component’s render() function renders the same result given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a performance boost in some cases.

## Code example of `PureComponent`:

You can check out the code sample, that I did for you.

You will see that the `Item` component is always rendered only 1 time, because we use `React.PureComponent`. To prove my statement, each time the `Item` is rendered, I added current time of rendering. From the example you will see that the `Item` `Rendered at:` time is always the same, **because it's rendered only 1 time**.

```js
const itemsReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  if (action.type === 'ADD_ITEM') return [ ...state, action.payload]

  return state
}

const addItem = item => ({
  type: 'ADD_ITEM',
  payload: item
})

class Item extends React.PureComponent {
  render () {
    // As you can see here, the `Item` is always rendered only 1 time,
    // because we use `React.PureComponent`.
    // You can check that the `Item` `Rendered at:` time is always the same.
    // If we do it with `React.Component`,
    // then the `Item` will be rerendered on each List update.
    return <div>{ this.props.name }, Rendered at: { Date.now() }</div>
  }
}

class List extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { intervalId: null }
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    // Add new item on each 1 second,
    // and keep its `id`, in order to clear the interval later
    const intervalId = setInterval(this.addItem, 1000)
    this.setState({ intervalId })
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    // Use intervalId from the state to clear the interval
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId)
  }

  addItem () {
    const id = Date.now()
    this.props.addItem({ id, name: `Item - ${id}` })
  }

  renderItems () {
    return this.props.items.map(item => <Item key={item.id} {...item} />)
  }

  render () {
    return <div>{this.renderItems()}</div>
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { addItem }
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ items: state })
const ListContainer = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(List)

const Store = Redux.createStore(itemsReducer)
const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={Store}>
    <ListContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.0/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.7/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.26.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

## Solutions:

1. If the performance problem is caused by `MyRow` rerending, please find out what's the reason of rerending, because it should not happen, because of `PureComponent` usage.

   - You can try to simplify your **reducer**, in order to check / debug, is the reducer causing the problem. For instance, just add the new item to the list (without doing anything else as filtrations, slice, etc): `myList: [ ...state.myList, payload ]`
   - Please make sure you always pass the same **`key`** to your item component `<MyRow key={list.id} data={list} />`. If the `key` or `data` props are changed, then the component will be rerendered.

---

2. Here are some other libraries, these stand for efficient rendering of lists. I'm sure they will give us some alternatives or insights:

   - [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) - *React components for efficiently rendering large lists and tabular data*
   - [react-infinite](https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite) - *A browser-ready efficient scrolling container based on UITableView*

---

Comment: Thanks. I had made the mistake of assuming a `PureComponent` is the same as a stateless component. They're not. A `PureComponent` has additional logic, it essentially contains a more strict version of `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Answer (score 2):

PureComponent will shallowly compare the props and state. So my guess here is that the items are somehow new objects than the previous passed props, thus the rerendering.

I would advice, in general, to only pass primitive values in pure components :

```
class MyList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.myList.map((item, index) => (
                    <MyRow key={item.id} id={item.id} name={data.name} />
                    //or it's alternative 
                    <MyRow key={item.id} {...item} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

//...

class MyRow extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        const {id, name} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {id} - {name}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem really exists in the reducer.

```
myList: [ payload, ...state.myList.filter(item => payload.id !== item.id).slice(0, -1) ]
```

What is the logic implemented using slice(0,-1)?

It is the culprit here.

From your question I understood the next state after [1,2,3] will be [1,2,3,4].

But your code will be giving [4,1,2], then [5,4,1] then [6,5,4].

Now all the elements in the state are new, not in the initial state. See state is not just getting appended it is completely changing.

Please see if you are getting the desired result by avoiding slice.

```
 myList: [ payload, ...state.myList.filter(item => payload.id !== item.id)]
```

Comment: Without `PureComponent`, each Item in the List will be rerendered, on a new Item being added. You can play with my example above. So `PureComponent` is required.

Comment: Yeah. My mistake. Edited the answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is quite an easy solution for this. React VDOM is just a diffing algorithm. The only piece missing with your JSX is something called **key** which is like an id that the diffing algo uses and renders the particular element. Just tag the element with a KEY something like this https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

```
<li key={number.toString()}>
    {number}   </li>
```

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you are creating a new array each time in the reducer in which all array indices need to be re-calculated. have you tried appending the new node to the end of the list instead of prepending?

Comment: Isn't this going to mutate the state? Also, array keys are fixed values from DB.

Comment: it mutates the redux state, yes, but I don't think state mutation is what causes your issue. I suspect that in your reducer, when receiving the action and calculating `myList`, you force React to re-render everything because the first, and all, items in the array change. if you were to append `payload`, versus prepend `payload`, React may be able to better handle your new data.

Comment: The original question is the right way to handle redux state. It's only making a shallow copy (even though the values are primitives, not references, so they'll pass `===` no matter what)