# How can saving React Child Components inside state value be efficient?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, ecmascript-6

I'm working on some project where I need to add react child components dynamically. While this task may seem to be easy to complete, I'm concerned about the efficiency of my approach. I surfed the internet and found several solutions that have the same design pattern as mine. Still, I'm doubting myself of efficiency.

Below is my example:

```
class Container extends Component{

    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
         children: []
      }
      this.addChild = this.addChild.bind(this)
    }

    addChild(){
      this.setState({
        children: [...this.state.children, 
                   <div> 
                      <h1> My number is {this.state.children.length} </h1>
                   </div>]
      })
    } 

    render() {
      return
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.addChild}> Add child </button>
                {this.state.children.map( child => child)}
            </div>
    }
}
```

This example is quite simple. But when you have a complex structure, where components have other components that change state, have events listeners and deep structure, **Component's** state value will contain a huge amount of code and this component will re-render everything on each addition. On **100th addition**, it will make **99 unnecessary** re-renders.

Of course, I can use **Vanilla JS** or **JQuery** to append new components, but I do not find it to be smart decision. I'd like to keep consistency and solve the problem with React tools.

What are your thoughts? What patterns would you suggest?

Comment: You can check `PureComponent` concept and try to organize your code around it. Here's an working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50463828/4312466

Comment: @JordanEnev thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 years after, I see that this approach is terrible. One should store **state values** in the **array** and iterate them in the render function. Not only the code will look more clear, but memory usage will decrease as well.

Comment: And yeah, people don't use Class components these days 

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've just found the answer for this question myself. While **React** invokes **render** **function** on each **state** **change**, it does not **re-render** unnecessary components.